# En el apartado full name de la consola quiero saber como hacer que aparezcan el nombre y el apellido separados y no juntos

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace EDADES
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string nombre;
            string apellido1;
            string fullName;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese nombre");
            nombre = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese apellido1");
            apellido1 = (Console.ReadLine());

            //FUllname
            Console.WriteLine("fullName");
            fullName = (nombre  + apellido1);
            Console.WriteLine("" + fullName);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4):

Solo contatenale un espacio en blanco y con eso sale

```
 fullName = (nombre  +" "+ apellido1);
```